# Code to check if SIM800L successfully sends a text message

Tags: arduino, esp32, nodemcu, sim800l

I wanted to know if there is any code to check if a sim800L successfully sends a text message. I will need this code so that every time my sim800L sends a text message successfully it would light up a LED light. I am also using a nodemcu-32S as my microcontroller and Arduino IDE.

here is my code for sending a text message

```
Serial.println(customKey);
Serial.println("SENDING CONFIRMATION TEXT");
sim800.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
delay(1000);
sim800.print("AT+CMGS=\""+PHONE+"\"\r");
delay(1000);
sim800.print("Completed");
sim800.print(",");
sim800.print(orderID);
delay(100);
sim800.write(0x1A); 
delay(1000);
Serial.println("SMS Sent Successfully.");
```

Answer (score 0):

See [AT command manual](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf) (found it online, I don't have the device myself) at chapter `4.2.5  AT+CMGS` - it looks like it should response, incl. whenever it succeeded.

Comment: Is there a way to store the responses of the sim800L in a variable?